# How do i set up an application on windows to respond to MAPISendMail calls?

Tags: windows, email, mapisendmail

The MAPISendMail function is available on windows so that an application can request that an email be sent. Windows will route the request to whichever email client is configured as the default provider.

How do I write an application so that it will act as an email client for the purpose of receiving the MAPISendMail emails? Can anyone point me to the MSDN documentation? Or let me know the required interfaces and registry keys involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some stuff in the registery to 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mapi

create a new key with your apps name
add a REG_EXPAND_SZ and assign the path to your dll to it
create a new key with name shell
create a new key with name open
create a new key with name command
assign your exe name to it.

PS. For vista and windows 7, use HKEY_LOCAL_USER

Implement the MAPI-API in your DLL.
You need the shell\open\command value to be set
else the client won't show up in the clients
list in your internet settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the Microsoft Exchange Transport Provider, you can implement a MAPI Spooler Hook Provider.  The following Microsoft Knowledgebase sample shows how to create a MAPI Spooler Hook Provider:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224362